# exclude value from feature analysis classification (ArcGIS extension)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, classification, feature-class, feature-extraction, extract-by-mask

I am using feature analysis to classify small (mm) round features from the landscape. I have calculated the circularity of each shape and I want to exclude those which are not round enough.

Does anyone know how to exclude specific values from a classification using feature analysis?

I'm also using ArcMap 10.2

Comment: To be clear, you have vector features? If so, do your features have the circularity calcs in the attributes?

Comment: Sorry, yes vector. Also yes i have the circularity, area and perimeter in the attributes table. :)